# Huge array with long paths and unknown keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have a huge array and for example here are paths to the elements (text data):

```
$content['start']**[0]**['teaser']**[14]**['body'][0]['markup'];
$content['start']**[1]**['teaser']**[98]**['body'][0]['markup'];
```

Is there any way to reach these elements if the keys (marked **) are variable?

With the first keys [0], [1] I could deal by using count(), but the second keys...

Comment: You can use variables as array keys

Comment: @John Conde, by saying 'variables' I meant keys (**) are dynamic/unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys) to get the keys. You didn't specify whether there would be multiple keys or not, so this example assumes one (unknown) key (you would have to use nested loops if multiple)

```
$key1 = array_keys($content['start']);
$key1 = $key1[0];

$key2 = array_keys($content['start'][$key1]['teaser']);
$key2 = $key2[0];

$value = $content['start'][$key1]['teaser'][$key2]['body'][0]['markup'];
```